# Get URL headers in PHP

Tags: php, request-headers

So, let's say I'm a client entering this URL on my blog website: `https://blogbyme.com/post?id=1`.
I want the server to see that URL and customize the page based off what post it is.
The main question is  - when the request is made, how do I grab the `id` header's value to send the correct blog post?

Right now I've  got this far.

```php
if (!function_exists('getallheaders')) {
    function getallheaders() {
    $headers = [];
    foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) {
        if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') {
            $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $headers;
    }
}
```

and that's still not working.

Comment: id is not a header, it is a GET parameter. Basically every PHP tutorial will cover that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the superglobal of PHP [`$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

```
echo $_GET["id"];
```

> I want the server to see that URL and customize the page based off what post it is. The main question is - when the request is made, how do I grab the id header's value to send the correct blog post?

You can get the full request URI from:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```